# Python API asyncio error - traceback script error

Tags: python, linux, api

I made a script with a friend, unluckily the script does not run smoothly. It fails at some point and gives the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "restClient.py", line 157, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(task)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 584, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "restClient.py", line 142, in func
    available = client.getStockAmount(_product)
  File "/root/brandcanyon/BrandCanyonApi/client.py", line 269, in getStockAmount
    productId, productVariantId = self.findProductIdAndVariantId(product.name, product.size)
  File "/root/brandcanyon/BrandCanyonApi/client.py", line 168, in findProductIdAndVariantId
    product = self.getProductById(productId)
  File "/root/brandcanyon/BrandCanyonApi/client.py", line 136, in getProductById
    product = response.json()['data']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 900, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The restClient.py File that the script is talking about is the following:

```
while True:
            for product in page1:
                    for variant in product.attributes['variants']:
                        print(variant.attributes)
                        print(product.attributes['title'])
                        print(variant.attributes['option2'])
                        _product = Product(
                            name = product.attributes['title'],
                            size = variant.attributes['option2']
                        )
                        shopify.InventoryLevel.set(
                            location_id = location_id, 
                            inventory_item_id = variant.inventory_item_id, 
                            available = client.getStockAmount(_product)
                        )
                        print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
            if page1.has_next_page():
                page1 = page1.next_page()       
            else:
                break
        print("Inventory Updated - Waiting 350 seconds for next Update")
        print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
        await asyncio.sleep(20)
        
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = loop.create_task(func())

try:
    loop.run_until_complete(task)
except asyncio.CancelledError:
    pass
```

Do you know the error? Can you help me out?

Thank you so much!

Comment: It works perfectly for the first time, after the loop starts it make the error.

Comment: It looks like your code is attempting to read the .json file more than once without closing it first. Reading a textfile to the end uses it up. And the json decoder is saying it can't find data in the file. That is generally what *Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)* means.

Comment: What is the function `func()`? Is it the infinite while loop at the top?

Comment: the func() is a function above the while loop yes!

Comment: so before the While True is this:

async def func():
location_id = shopify.Location.find()[0].attributes['id']
        orders = {}
        sampleShopifyResponse = {}

Comment: Seems like its working fine but somehow after 30-40-50 minutes of doing the loop it fails with the error

Comment: There are actually two While True things in the func, one above and one and the bottom. Not sure